# How to detect css properties in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, tree

i want to detect css `display` from div. If `display:block`, change icon to `-` and if `display:none` change icon to `+`.

I try this code but won't works.

```
if($('#ceo').css('display') == 'none'){ 
    $("#button img").css({top:"-18px"});
} else {
    $("#button img").css({top:"9px"});
}
```

I want to make collapsible tree structure.
This my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9jYL/)

Comment: What exactly does not work? Everything seems ok in your fiddle

Comment: @imkost As you can see, there is `+` and `-` button. I want to when the (CEO) is show, the `+` in BOC button change to `-` button.

Comment: The problem is that after you click you will get the correct minus, but then you hover function triggers again and replaces it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make a big changes and rewrite some code. It look good now : 
See [demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/james_nguyen/t9jYL/18/)

```
function transform(element, direct) {
    var value;
    if (direct == 1) {
        value = "9px";
    } else {
        value = "-18px";
    }
    $("img", element).stop().animate({
        top: value
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 200
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        // Check if #ceo display:block, set image to minus
        if ($('#ceo').css('display') == 'none') {
            transform($("#button"), 1);
        } else {
            transform($("#button"), 2);
        }
        $("#ceo").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
        $("#button2").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    });

    $("#button2").click(function () {
        if ($('#division').css('display') == 'none') {
            transform($("#button2"), 1);
        } else {
            transform($("#button2"), 2);
        }
        $("#division").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I myself am not very good in JS. The code I have in http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/DESkX/1/ works but I'm sure it can be leaner than what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){

        // Check if #ceo display:block, set image to minus
        if($('#ceo').css('display') == 'none'){ 
            $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"9px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
        } else {
            $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"-18px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
        }

        $("#ceo").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
        $("#button2").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){  
        if ($("#division").css('display') == 'none') {
            $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"9px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
        } else {
            $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"-18px"},{queue:false,duration:200});                    
        }

        $("#division").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    });

});
```

Comment: Clean code, everything works :D thanks before. I must search the different with my code. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get actual display value using computed style.

```
window.getComputedStyle( document.getElementById("#ceo"), null).getPropertyValue("display")
```

> $('#ceo').css('display')
>   only shows inline style display value.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this javascript code

```
function changeImage()
{
element=document.getElementById('myimage')
if (element.src.match("maximze_icon"))
  {
  element.src="images/minimize_icon.gif";
  }
else
  {
  element.src="images/maximze_icon.gif"; 
  }
}
var state = 'block';

function showhide(layer_ref) {

if (state == 'block') {
state = 'none';
}
else {
state = 'block';
}
if (document.all) { //IS IE 4 or 5 (or 6 beta)
eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display = state");
}
if (document.layers) { //IS NETSCAPE 4 or below
document.layers[layer_ref].display = state;
}
if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) {
hza = document.getElementById(layer_ref);
hza.style.display = state;
}
}
```

and html code is as below try it....

```
<img id="myimage" onclick="showhide('div1'); changeImage()" src="images/minimize_icon.gif"><a href="#" onclick="showhide('div1'); changeImage()">Root</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be exactly what you looking:

```
$(function(){
    $("#button2").hover(function(){
        $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"9px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
    }, function() {
        $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"-18px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){

        // Check if #ceo display:block, set image to minus
        if($('#ceo').css('display') == 'none'){ 
            $("#button img").css({top:"9px"});
        } else {
            $("#button img").css({top:"-18px"});
        }

        $("#ceo").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
        $("#button2").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#division").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    });
});
```

[Demo Here>>](http://jsfiddle.net/t9jYL/15/)

Comment: I already check your code :) but it not work in top button :(
But it solved now. Thanks for your response. I get many knowledge now.